# Regexp to validate URL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, pattern-matching

I have tried several regex patterns (designed for use with PHP because I couldn't find any for MySQL) for URL validation, but none of them are working. Probably MySQL has a slightly different syntax.

I've also tried to come up with one, but no success.

So does anyone know a fairly good regex to use with MySQL for URL validation?

Comment: What do you want to validate? If the input string is a valid URL that can be resolved?

Comment: No, I want to `SELECT` all rows which don't match the URL pattern. (So all invalid URLs)

Comment: What kind of URLs are allowed? How strict validation are you thinking of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to article [11.5.2. Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) in [MySQL's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/), you can perform selections with a regular expression with the following syntax

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE field REGEX pattern
```

In order to match simple URLS, you may use

```
SELECT field FROM table
 WHERE field REGEXP "^(https?://|www\\.)[\.A-Za-z0-9\-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"
```

This will match most urls like

- www.google.il
- http://google.com/
- http://ww.google.net/
- www.google.com/index.php?test=data
- https://yahoo.dk/as
- http://goo.gle.com/
- http://wt.a.x24-s.org/ye/
- www.website.info

But not

- htp://google.com
- ww.google.com/
- www-google.com
- http://google.c
- http://goo#.com
- httpf://google.com

Comment: That's amazing. Just one more question. Would it be possible to make the `http://` or `www` optional? I want it to also match `example.com` or `subdomain.example.com`. Would that be easy?

Comment: Make it optional? Where? If you're talking about when inserting, this should all be done prior to inserting, so you wouldn't even need to match urls when selecting. Regarding your question, yes that would be easy to do, but it'd also mean stuff like backup.2012-01-27.xml would get matched.

Comment: Note that `http://about.museum` would not be matched as valid, but `www.foo.bar, with spaces!` would pass as valid.

Comment: Does not work with new domains. Does not work with foreign characters either.
дизайнрекламы.рф, online.solutions etc.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer KBA posted works, there are some inconstancies with the escaping.

The proper syntax should be, this syntax works in MySQL as well as in PHP for example.

```
SELECT field FROM table
 WHERE field REGEXP "^(https?:\/\/|www\.)[\.A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"
```

The above code will only match if the content of 'field' starts with a URL. If you would like to match all rows where the field contains a url (so for example surrounded by other text / content) just simply use:

```
SELECT field FROM table
 WHERE field REGEXP "(https?:\/\/|www\.)[\.A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"
```