# not working in searching incomplete words in mysql multiple search

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql code in which you can search multiple words and display for possible results

employee table

```
ID firstname  lastname      bandname
------------------------------------
 1 John       Lennon        Beatles
 2 Paul       Mccartney     Beatles
 3 Ringo      Starr         Beatles
 4 George     Harrison      Beatles
```

in here when you typed "John Paul" the result is John Lennon and Paul Mccartney

the query is

```
set @search = 'George Ringo';

SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE @search LIKE CONCAT('%',id,'%')
   OR @search LIKE CONCAT('%',firstname,'%')
   OR @search LIKE CONCAT('%',lastname,'%');

set @search = '1 Paul Starr';

SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE @search LIKE CONCAT('%',id,'%')
   OR @search LIKE CONCAT('%',firstname,'%')
   OR @search LIKE CONCAT('%',lastname,'%');
```

but the problem here now is when i typed "Geor" or "Pau" there is no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. I used REGEXP

```
WHERE field1 REGEXP(@search)
    OR field2 REGEXP(@search)
    OR field3 REGEXP(@search
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing column name and search value. can you try this?

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE id LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%')
   OR firstname LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%')
   OR lastname LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%')
```

### UPDATE

In your case both `LIKE %keyword%` and `REGEXP ('keyword')` produce same result.  I would like to provide more information about `TEXT SEARCH`.

#### LIKE('keyword%')

**pros**: AS many people already know, this is searched by index scan. so it's fast. 
**cons**: But, This is not what OP wants. just search prefix matching.

#### LIKE('%keyword%')

**pros** : can search any value contains 'keyword', **cons**:It's slow.

#### REXEXP('keyword')

**pros** : this provides *Powerful Regular Expressions* e.g refer to [Regexp to validate URL in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033018/regexp-to-validate-url-in-mysql) search url pattern. **cons** : It's slow.

#### FTS(FULLTEXT SEARCH)

**pros** : yes. It's hyper fast, **cons**: Only MyISAM supports FTS. (exceptional, in MySQL 5.6 InnoDB can use FTS. refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html)

#### using Search Engine

integration  with Solr, ElasticSearch, Sphinx...

**pros** : very fast. **cons**: Yet difficult to use. there are few references rather than MySQL FTS. There is a little delay can be searched new inserted or updated value.

### My Test Result

I have tested to show how long take each search method. but Search Engine has not been tested. MySQL 5.5 used, MyISAM (to check FTS). There are over 15M records in search_test.

LIKE 'robert%' : 0.00 sec

LIKE '%robert%' : 9.73 sec

REGEXP ('robert') : 9.16 sec

MATCH(value)  Against('*robert*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) : 0.02 sec

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*)
FROM search_test
WHERE value LIKE 'robert%';
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|     3441 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*)
FROM search_test
WHERE value LIKE '%robert%';
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|     5034 |
+----------+
1 row in set (9.73 sec)

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*)
FROM search_test
WHERE value REGEXP ('robert');
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|     5034 |
+----------+
1 row in set (9.16 sec)

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*)
FROM search_test
WHERE MATCH(value)  Against('*robert*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|     3505 | <= not 5034, maybe stopword matters? I'm not sure. sorry.
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: but the answer that i found is working. thanks for your response :)