# Regex to SQL: repetition-operator operand invalid

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'm trying to use a regex to detect URLs in all the rows of my table, here's the regex

```
\b(([\w-]+:\/\/?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|\/)))
```

However, I invariably get the "**repetition-operator operand invalid**" error, which, after hours of search on the internet, still remains obscure.
Where have I gone wrong? What can I do to fix this? And alternaltively, is there a better way to detect URLs in messages in SQL other than a Regex?

Thank you.

Comment: What about [Regexp to validate URL in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9033154/3832970)? Does it answer your question?

Comment: @stribizhev I might need a more complex regex, otherwise not all URLs would be detected. The one above worked for me perfectly, and if I can help it, I would like to keep working with it.

Comment: @stribizhev Getting the Repetition error for this one. As for the regex you suggested, I tried it, and it only detects a small portions of my URLs.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with using `?` quantifier, `*?` and `+?` cannot be used in MySQL regexp. Also, not sure about non-capturing groups, replace them with capturing ones. Please re-try with `[[:<:]](([a-zA-Z0-9-]+:\/\/*|www[.])[^ ()<>]+(\([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\)|([^ [:punct:]]|\/)))`.

Comment: @stribizhev It works this. But the results improved just slightly. Are you sure that the regex hasn't changed at all? (This new syntax boggles me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `?` quantifier in [MySQL regex](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) as the syntax is POSIX-based. Still, you can use `*` to match 0 or more characters. Also, `\b` in MySQL regex should be replaced with `[[:<:]]` (since this matches at the beginning of a word).

Thus, I suggest using

```
[[:<:]](([a-zA-Z0-9-]+:\/\/*|www[.])[^ ()<>]+(\([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\)|([^ [:punct:]]|\/)))
```

I am expanding `\w` to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` as it is exactly what `\w` is. Instead of `\s`, I am using a literal space. Instead of `\d`, I am using `[0-9]`. This is done for readability and better compatibility. If `\w`, `\d` and `\s` work for you, you can use them, but I do not see them among the supported entities in [POSIX specs](http://linux.die.net/man/7/regex).

Also, instead of literal space, you could use `[:space:]`, it matches *space, tab, newline, and carriage return*. Instead of `[a-zA-Z]` you can use `[:alpha:]`, and instead of `[0-9]`, you can use `[:digit:]`. Please also check this:

```
[[:<:]](([[:alpha:][:digit:]-]+:\/\/*|www[.])[^[:space:]()<>]+(\([[:alpha:][:digit:]_]+\)|([^[:space:][:punct:]]|\/)))
```

Comment: It's working flawlessly this time. I'll make sure to read thoroughly through your answer so as to not get stuck twice.

Thank you very much. And good day to you.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, I have just found an URL matching regex [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3508509/3832970) and tried to adapt it for you: `[[:<:]](https*://)*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.(\.*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)+`. No idea if it works better.