# RegEx from Javascript to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, regex

I've this javascript regular expression that check if an URI is valid (RFC 3986):

```
/^(https?):\/\/((?:[a-z0-9.-]|%[0-9A-F]{2}){3,})(?::(\d+))?((?:\/(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)*)(?:\?((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?(?:#((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?$/i
```

Now i need to convert that in a MySQL query, using `REGEXP`.

Eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name t
WHERE t.uri REGEXP '....'
```

Could you help me?

Comment: What is MySql version?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033018/regexp-to-validate-url-in-mysql

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew MySql version is 5.7.24-enterprise-commercial-advanced

Comment: @dbramwell this solution is more generic, i need to respect the RFC 3986

Comment: 1) Double all `'` chars inside `'...'` string literals. 2) Replace all `(?:` with `(`. 3) Certainly remove the first `/` and last `/i` and all `\/` with `/`, 4) Replace `\d` with `[0-9]`. 5) Most likely, replace `\?` with ``\\?``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- Double all `'` chars inside `'...'` string literals
- Replace all `(?:` with `(` as MySQL legacy versions used a POSIX compliant regex engine that does not support non-capturing groups
- Certainly remove the first `/` and last `/i` since the pattern is passed as a string in MySQL,  not as a regex literal, and the pattern is case insensitive by default, no need to add `i` anywhere (or add `A-Z` manually in case some global settings are overridden)
- Replace all `\/` with `/` just to keep the regex clean
- Replace `\d` with `[0-9]` (again, POSIX is not aware of shorthand character classes, although you may also use POSIX character classes, e.g. `[[:digit:]]` to match any digit)
- Most likely, replace `\?` with `\\?`, or just use `[?]` to match  a literal `?` symbol
- Always use a literal hyphen at the end or start of a character class (bracket expression in POSIX regex).

Use

```
WHERE t.uri REGEXP '^https?://(([A-Za-z0-9.-]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}){3,})(:[0-9]+)?((/([A-Za-z0-9._~!$&''()*+,;=:@-]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*)*)([?](([A-Za-z0-9._~!$&''()*+,;=:/?@-]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*))?(#(([A-Za-z0-9._~!$&''()*+,;=:/?@-]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*))?$'
```